# Remove Windows 8 annoying Menu

Tags: windows

I bought a dell laptop which comes without o/s, so I buy Windows 8.1 DVD and install in the new machine.

The problem is, every time when I am doing something, Windows popup a Black bar on the right hand side showing some basic buttons (Search, Share, Start, Devices, Settings), a small popup also appear on the bottom right showing current time, Wifi signal and battery life.

I pops 10-15 times within an hour. Its really frustrating when I am typing something or filling some password etc and atonce my focus from the current screen removes and I see that annoying black menu.

I even don't know this menu name.

Can an expert help me removing this menu.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's called the "charm bar" (yes, really) but I don't know why it would pop up unexpectedly. Still, this site is about programming, so you'll need to ask this on the sister site http://superuser.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That menu is called the Charms bar, and appears when you move the mouse to the top or bottom right corners and keep it there for a few seconds.